# Sql, how to select many results based on two dependent columns in a single select?

Tags: c#, sql

I have `table_A` with columns `guid_A` and `guid_B` and the table has primary key `(guid_A, guid_B)`. I want to select out all the guid pairs that exist in an `IEnumerable<Tuple<Guid, Guid>>` I have in my application, but I'm not sure how to most efficiently do this. most naively I could make repeated calls to:

```
SELECT guid_A, guid_B
FROM table_A
WHERE guid_A = @guidA AND guid_B = @guidB
```

as I iterate of my `IEnumerable<Tuple<Guid, Guid>>` setting the parameters as their respective values from the `Tuple` but this could mean many calls to the DB.

I thought I could change my `IEnumerable` to a `Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>> where the key Guid is guid_A and the value is an`IEnumerable` of all the guid_B's that appear with that guid_A and instead use a select like.

```
SELECT guid_A, guid_B
FROM table_A
WHERE guid_A = @guidA AND guid_B in (...a list of guids...)
```

as I iterate over the `Dictionary` building up the list of guids as I go. This way I only need to make one call per guid_A I have in my `Dictionary` Keys. But I had hoped there may be a better way of approaching this that would help me select all the existing pairs of guid_A, guid_B from a list in a single SELECT query?

Comment: Dump your lookup pairs into a temp table and use a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a stored procedure that accepts a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

To do this, you first need to create a type in your database to use as the type for the parameter to the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE TVP_Guids AS TABLE(
  GUID_A UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ,
  GUID_B UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Then you need to create the procedure using the type and your table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE s_Get_GUIDs
  @TVPGuids TVP_Guids READONLY
AS
  SELECT *
    FROM table_A t INNER JOIN @TVPGuids g 
      ON t.GUID_A = g.GUID_A 
     AND t.GUID_B = t.GUID_B
GO
```

Finally, you need to populate the parameter in your code:

```
// Placeholder for the real collection
IEnumerable<Tuple<Guid, Guid>> cGUIDs;

// create a data table that will be used to hold your GUIDs
var oTable = new DataTable("GUIDs");
oTable.Columns.Add("GUID_A", typeof(Guid));
oTable.Columns.Add("GUID_B", typeof(Guid));

// Add each of the guids from ienumerable to the datatable
foreach (var oTuple in cGUIDs)
{
    oTable.Rows.Add(oTuple.Item1, oTuple.Item2);
}

using (var oConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=YourDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    oConnection.Open();
    using (var oCommand = new SqlCommand("s_Get_GUIDs", oConnection))
    {
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var oParameter = oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TVPGuids", oTable);
        // This is necessary so ado.net knows we are passing a table-valued parameter
        oParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

        oCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // ToDo: Add remaining code here

    }
    oConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the relative sizes of the in-memory list and the database table?

If the in-memory list is large and the DB table smaller it's possible that loading the entire table into memory and then using LINQ to join the 2 objects would be most efficient.